# How to invite user's friends using Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm letting users login to my site using the Graph API. I'm able to access a list of all their friends using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`.

My question is, how can I invite their friends to the site after that? Do I have to show that invite/request form, or can I invite their friends in any other way?

If I do have to show the invite/request form, is there a way to select all friends with a click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked this, but my guess is that you have to show the invite dialog.
Facebook policy is to not allow apps to do too much without user interaction. You can do whatever you want with the user, he gave you permissions, thats his problem.
His friends are another story. Other people should not suffer because one of their friends authorized a spammy app (not that I'm saying this is the case with your app :))

Comment: I have thought about this a little. Let say you want to use the graph API and get the list of the users friends. Ok, you have it. What now? You want to send them invitations? You cant. You need thier permissions as well. Thats why you need the facebook dialog. This way, its not your app doing the invite, its the facebook architecture. I think :)

Comment: How do I get a down vote over a year later for an answer that was marked as correct? :)